# TypeError: Object #<MongoClient> has no method 'db' solution vs Documentation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

While going through a mongodb tutorial, I ran into an issue with this configuration:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new server('localhost', '27017', {'native_parser': true}))
var db = mongoClient.db('test');
```

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'db'

Eventually, I was able to solve it using mongodb server

```
var server      = require('mongodb').Server,
    Db          = require('mongodb').Db;

var db =new Db('test', new server('localhost', '27017', {'native_parser': true}));
db.open(function(err, res){
    app.listen(8080);
    console.dir('app started on 8080');
});
```

However, [the documentation says](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api) "Server should not be used, use the MongoClient.connect."
[image]

Based on this, I'd like to know when is the appropriate time to use the server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use it in regards to the deprecation present in 2.0 and your setup and usage of callbacks instead of promises:

```
var mongoDB =  require('mongodb');

var theDB = null;
mongoDB
    .MongoClient
    .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', null, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            theDB = db;
            app.listen(8080);
            console.dir('app started on 8080');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, @asa, I know the MongoClient works fine. What I really want to know is where to use the client in place of the server or Vice versa, not an example of mongoClient.

Comment: not sure if I understood you correctly, but if that's the case, you might be misled by the "server" name of the object you are referring to in your op. it was never meant to be used to create a database server instance a such, but a connection to a server, hence the misleading name and deprecation. Think of it as a DataSource in Java and JDBC connector.